# PyQT : Transfer between two TableView

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would like to transfer data between two QtTableView. To do that, I first select the row to transfer then click on "to_X_table".

But I don't understand how to fill the second tableview with the first one.
I tried :

```
self.to_X_table.clicked.connect(self.to_X_tableView)
def to_X_tableView(self):
    self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.tableWidget_Input_Col.selectionModel())
    self.tableView_X.setModel(self.proxy)
    self.tableView_X.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

I get this message :

```
TypeError : setSourceModel(self,‌​QAbstractItemModel) : 1 argument unexpected type QItemSelectionModel
```

I'dont really know what self.tableWidget_Input_Col.selectionModel() return. I guess it was a model. But seems not.

I also tried to create my own model like this (following this post [Get data from every cell from a QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280061/get-data-from-every-cell-from-a-qtableview))

```
def to_X_tableView(self):
    indexes = self.tableWidget_Input_Col.selectionModel().selectedRows()
    self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    for index in sorted(indexes):
        print('Row %d is selected' % index.row())
        self.model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
                QtGui.QStandardItem(self.tableWidget_Input_Col.model.index(index.row, 0))) 

    self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.tableWidget_Input_Col.selectionModel())
    self.tableView_X.setModel(self.proxy)
    self.tableView_X.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

but I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ChartGUI.py", line 151, in to_X_tableView
    QtGui.QStandardItem(self.tableWidget_Input_Col.model.index(index.row, 0)

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Comment: What was the result when you tried this?  If there was an error, please post the traceback.

Comment: TypeError : setSourceModel(self,QAbstractItemModel) : 1 argument unexpected type QItemSelectionModel. Can't fint python doc on that (only c++ doc https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html)

Comment: Actually if you edit your original post, so the formatting is easier to read, and post the full traceback, that would be the most useful.  Although it looks like the error is on the fourth line, and whatever you're calling from `self.tableWidget_Input_Col.selectionModel()` isn't an argument of the type that `self.proxy.setSourceModel()` expects to receive.  It's also helpful if you post anything you've already tried too.

Comment: Yes I expected than `self.tableWidget_In‌​put_Col.selectionMode‌​l()`  return a model but in fact it returns QItemSelectionModel. So I don't know how to get a "Sub model"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I solve my problem. I didn't consider the model the first time.
Here :

```
    self.modelX = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    indexes = self.tableWidget_Input_Col.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
    temp=self.tableWidget_Input_Col.selectionModel().model() # need to consider the model !

    for index in sorted(indexes):
        self.modelX.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
                QtGui.QStandardItem(str(temp.data(index))))   

    self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.modelX)
    self.tableView_X.setModel(self.proxy)
    self.tableView_X.resizeColumnsToContents()
```