# PyQt 4 extracting all information from a QTableWidget into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pyqt

I am wondering whether it is possible to extract all the data from a QTableWidget into a Pandas Dataframe.

At the moment I can only find information of how to [extract information into a QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280061/get-data-from-every-cell-from-a-qtableview).

I understand that the QTable view is inherited by the QTableWidget but when I adapt the above solution with the code below it returns the error that 'QTableWidget' object has no attribute 'index'. I have not found any information of how to convert the [QTableWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html) into a [QTableView](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtableview.html)

```
data = []
        for row in range(QtGui.QTableWidget.rowCount()):
          data.append([])
          for column in range(QtGui.QTableWidget.columnCount()):
            index = QtGui.QTableWidget.index(row, column)
            data[row].append(str(QtGui.QTableWidget.data(index).toString()))
```

My end goal is to get the data into a Pandas dataframe which I think will be easy once the data list is populated; however I would be interested to know if there is a more direct approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was able to put it into a dataset using:

```
    data = []
    for row in allRows:
        newRow = []
        for column in xrange(8):
            newRow.append(str(QtGui.QTableWidget.item(row,column).text()))
        data.append(newRow)
```

This creates a new nested list with each item in the list representing a column in the row.

Answer (score 0):

In your syntax your use index but rewrite to item

```
self.table=QtWidget.QTableWidget()
datas = []
        for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
          data=[]
          for column in range(QtGui.QTableWidget.columnCount()):
            texte = (self.table.item(row, column)).text()
            data.append(texte)
          datas.append(data)
```

Comment: Hi, can you add some code with an example too to explain your answer, we need to do this in order to help someone who is trying to read the answer understand it better